# Spring example application does not take tomcat application path into account

Tags: java, spring, config, web-deployment

I have trying to run [this Spring example](http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.nl/2012/01/spring-31-mvc-example.html) on a localhost Tomcat 7 installation. I am using cargo to depoy the war with the following coordinates:

```
<deployable>
    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sleepless</artifactId>
    <type>war</type>
</deployable>
```

When I access the app from Tomcat manager, it brings me to:

```
http://localhost:8080/sleepless-1.0/home.html;jsessionid=DFBD9DB5B15416188D9E45A7FDC0D375
```

and that's very fine. When I click on a page link, it brings me to (for example):

```
http://localhost:8080/searchFlights.html
```

The `/sleepless-1.0` part is missing and I get a 404. How can I make sure this spring example adds the missing part to all pages? What is the missing configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is generated like this:

```
<a href="/searchFlights.html" title="Flights">
```

So it completely ignores the context path of the webapp (and doesn't support URL-rewriting as a mean to track sessions). It should use the JSTL `<c:url>` tag:

```
<a href="<c:url value='/searchFlights.html'/>" title="Flights">
```

Comment: I love stackoverflow, really! Indeed you are right, the author failed to use c:url in default.jsp. Woaw...